# Implement Mutex solution for axios

Tags: reactjs, concurrency, axios, mutex

If your application has multiple concurrent API calls and you may have scenarios where you want to stop and control their triggering. I am talking about a mutex solution for API service which allows locking and unlocking of API to control web services.

Let’s say our app needs an API token to be passed in headers for authorization. We would want to fetch this token before any APIs are triggered from the browser. In case when this token expires we would again fetch a new token. All other APIs from the browser should wait for a new token and then trigger.

Answer (score 0):

First, we create axios instance

```
import APILockService from '../APILockService';
import axios from 'axios'; 

function apiRequestLockInterceptor(config) {
  if(APILockService.isLocked(config)) { 
   await APILockService.waitTillUnlocked(); 
  } 
return config; 
} 

const instance = axios.create(); 
instance.interceptors.request.use(apiRequestLockInterceptor);

export instance;
```

Create the APILockService which will manage the loacking, unlocking and wait for APIs

```
class APILockService {
    constructor() {
        this.locked = false
        this.lockToken = null;
    }

    lock = (lockToken) => {
        if(this.locked){
            throw new Error('APIService has already been locked.');
        }
        this.lockToken = lockToken;
        this.locked = true;
    }

    isLocked = (config) => {
        if(config.lockToken === this.lockToken){ //We do not want to block the API request which placed the lock in first place
            return false;
        }
        return this.locked;
    }

    releaseLock = (lockToken, resolve) => {
        if(lockToken === this.lockToken){
            this.locked = false;
            if(typeof this.resolveWaitPromise === 'function') {
                this.resolveWaitPromise();
            }
        }
    }

    waitTillUnlocked = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.resolveWaitPromise = () => {
                resolve();
            }
            setTimeout(() =>{
                this.locked = false;
                resolve();
            }, 300000);// timeout after 5 mins
        });
    }
}

const apiServiceInstance = new APILockService();

export default apiServiceInstance;
```

The lock token is a way of identifying the API call which placed the lock. We do not want to block this API.

We use APILockService something like this

```
function getAppToken() {  
  const lockToken = new Date().toISOString();  
  const options = {  
    method: ‘get’,  
    headers: { ‘content-type’: ‘application/x-www-form-urlencoded’},  
    data: qs.stringify(data),  
    url: ‘/app/token?userId=123’,  
    lockToken  
  };

  APILockService.lock(lockToken);  
  return axios(options)  
  .then(response => {  
    APILockService.releaseLock(lockToken);  
    return response.token  
  });  
}
```